# Alamofire 4.0 Upload MultipartFormData Header

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift3, alamofireimage

How do we add an authentication header to the upload function of Alamofire 4.0?

below is the sample code, however I see no way in adding a header to the function.

```
Alamofire.upload(
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(unicornImageURL, withName: "unicorn")
        multipartFormData.append(rainbowImageURL, withName: "rainbow")
    },
    to: "https://httpbin.org/post",
    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response)
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
)
```

Previous version of alamofire supported adding header directly, but not the new one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I got the solution.

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:{ multipartFormData in
         multipartFormData.append(unicornImageURL, withName: "unicorn")
         multipartFormData.append(rainbowImageURL, withName: "rainbow")},
       usingThreshold:UInt64.init(),
       to:"https://httpbin.org/post",
       method:.post, 
       headers:["Authorization": "auth_token"], 
       encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response)
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    })
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. I have one question related image upload with its progress. If you know then can you please help me? I have added question on SO now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631823/swift-3-alamofilre-4-0-multipart-upload-with-progress.

Comment: how about audio file in Alamofire 4? - i try to send a audio file in this form : multipartFormData.append(audioLocalPath, withName: "file", fileName: "file", mimeType: "application/octet-stream") but occur this error : multipartEncodingFailed(Alamofire.AFError.MultipartEncodingFailureReason.bodyPartFileNotReachableWithError(file:///var/mobile/Containers/....... /Documents/item.mp3, NSUnderlyingError=0x16049100 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}})) - where is problem? -bad request or bad audio path?

Comment: Ekta, I know I shouldn't put comments like this, but I had too. This small piece of code was very useful! worked perfectly!! THANK YOU!!

Comment: how to add parameters with upload,can you halp me.

Comment: @Malleswari yes. What you want ?

Comment: i want to pass  - method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: ["Authorization": "auth_token"], using Alamofire.upload()

Comment: @Malleswari please check my answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809867/alamofire-4-upload-with-parameters/39825225#39825225

Comment: hi @EktaPadaliya , could you please help my problem in uploading using alamofire ? tahnks in advance , maybe you have the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327062/how-to-upload-an-image-using-alamofire-multipart-form-data-with-basic-authentica

Comment: let url = try! URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!, method: .post, headers: headers)