# Swift 3 - Alamofilre 4.0 multipart image upload with progress

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift3

I've done with image upload and its successfully uploaded on server using below method.

Now I want to upload image with its progress so can any one tell me how to do? I found on everywhere but didn't got the correct solution.

**Code for image upload without it's progress :**

```
@IBAction func uploadClick(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    // define parameters
    let parameters = [
        "file_name": "swift_file.jpeg"
    ]

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.photoImageView.image!, 0.5)!, withName: "photo_path", fileName: "swift_file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
        }
        }, to:"http://server1/upload_img.php")
    { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.responseJSON { response in
                //self.delegate?.showSuccessAlert()
                print(response.request)  // original URL request
                print(response.response) // URL response
                print(response.data)     // server data
                print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
                //                        self.showSuccesAlert()
                //self.removeImage("frame", fileExtension: "txt")
                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                }
            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            //self.delegate?.showFailAlert()
            print(encodingError)
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Finally got the solution after search a lot. We just need to put uploadProgress block within result block.

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.photoImageView.image!, 0.5)!, withName: "photo_path", fileName: "swift_file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
        }
        }, to:"http://server1/upload_img.php")
    { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (Progress) in
                print("Upload Progress: \(Progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })

            upload.responseJSON { response in
                //self.delegate?.showSuccessAlert()
                print(response.request)  // original URL request
                print(response.response) // URL response
                print(response.data)     // server data
                print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
                //                        self.showSuccesAlert()
                //self.removeImage("frame", fileExtension: "txt")
                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                }
            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            //self.delegate?.showFailAlert()
            print(encodingError)
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i was looking for answer for ages now, finally i can see my image on the server