# Uploading an image to server using Alamofire not working

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I want to send an image from gallery to server in an API call. This image has to be passed as a parameter. To pass the image as a parameter, I tried to get the url of the image like so but it wasn't giving the correct url..

```
var selectedImage : UIImage = image
let imageData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(selectedImage)! as NSData
let imageStr = imageData.base64EncodedString(options:.endLineWithCarriageReturn)
imageArray.append(image)
```

Also I tried to upload the image like so...

```
        for img in imageArray {

            let url = "http://myApp..com/a/images_upload"
            let headers = [ "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]

            let URL = try! URLRequest(url: url, method: .post, headers: headers)
            let parameters =
                [
                    "access_token": accessToken
                    "image": img
                    ] as [String : Any]


            let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.2)!

            Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
                multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "image",fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "file")
                for (key, value) in parameters {
                    multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
                }
            }, with: URL) { (result) in
                switch result {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):

                    upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                        print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                    })

                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        print(response.result.value)
                        if let value = response.result.value {                                
                            print("IMG UPLOADED!!!")
                        }
                    }
                    case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print(“ERROR”)
}}}
```

But this is also crashing. I've been having this issue for quite some time now...not able to figure out what the exact solution is...Hope someone can help...:) Also did go through a lot of similar questions on SO. But couldn't find a solution till...

**EDIT:** My parameters are:

```
let Parameters =
                    [
                        "access_token": commonVarForAccessToken,
                        "seller_id": idForNewOldUser, 
                        "product_id": self.productId,
                        "is_default": "1",
                        "sequence": 1,
                        "image": self.localPath
                        ] as [String : Any]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631823/swift-3-alamofilre-4-0-multipart-image-upload-with-progress and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39809867/alamofire-4-upload-with-parameters

Comment: did go through that before, @iPatel...But it wasn't of help...

Comment: use my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45651187/upload-photo-file-with-json-and-custom-headers-via-swift-3-and-alamofire-4-i/46116478#46116478 Just pass your image in dictionary with key

Comment: I'm confused if it can be used  in my scenario...?what is your opinion, @JitendraModi ?

Comment: It is very easy to implement, Just declare a class of above and below is the use of that class.

Comment: Rename your `var`s `URL` and `Parameters` to lower case, now it's confusing you and everyone.

Comment: Theres a url already in lowercase so gave the other url in caps.. have changed the parameters to lowercase btw if it was confusing...:)

Comment: Bit confused regarding where to use your class, @ JitendraModi..also what is self.webservice... ?

Comment: Can you at least show us the crash logs?

Comment: The crash tells something like...Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftTypePreservingNSNumber dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608

Answer (score 0):

First use this Function for making URLRequest.

```
 func makeUrlRequestWithComponents(urlString:String, parameters:Dictionary<String, Any>, imageData:NSData) -> (URLRequestConvertible, NSData) {

// create url request to send
let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = Alamofire.Method.POST.rawValue
let boundaryConstant = "myRandomBoundary12345";
let contentType = "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundaryConstant
mutableURLRequest.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")



// create upload data to send
let uploadData = NSMutableData()

// add image
uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"file.png\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
uploadData.appendData("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
uploadData.appendData(imageData)

// add parameters
for (key, value) in parameters {
    uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n\(value)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
}
uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)



// return URLRequestConvertible and NSData
return (Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: nil).0, uploadData)
 }
```

And then this is the function to upload Image.

```
func uploadImage()
{

    let Parameters =
   [
"access_token": commonVarForAccessToken,
"seller_id": idForNewOldUser,
"product_id": self.productId,
"is_default": "1",
"sequence": 1,
] as [String : Any]


// example image data

let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImageView.image!,1)



// CREATE AND SEND REQUEST ----------

 let urlRequest = makeUrlRequestWithComponents("http://myApp..com/a/images_upload", parameters:      parameters, imageData: imageData)

  Alamofire.upload(urlRequest.0, urlRequest.1).progress { (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) in
    println("\(totalBytesWritten) / \(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)")
}
.responseJSON { (request, response, JSON, error) in
    println("REQUEST \(request)")
    println("RESPONSE \(response)")
    println("JSON \(JSON)")
    println("ERROR \(error)")
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @Zee, but I pick the image from the gallery. So should that image not be converted to its url first...?

Comment: You can pick image from gallery and assign it to UIImageView and then use it  in that function

Comment: also, you have given a proper filename of the image that is to be uploaded like so...imageFileName.jpg. But if I pick an image from gallery then that image won't have such a definite name. So what are we to do in such a case...?

Comment: this is optional and this is not my image file nam.

Comment: variable named (data) will define every thing

Comment: Ok..so you are saying that..name: "image_1", and fileName: "imageFileName.jpg" can be ommitted..?

Comment: OK..and one more thing ...this function is called on any action we require right...?

Comment: the apiToken that you have mentioned is the parameter right...?

Comment: but i have actually not one but about 5 different parameters..so where can those be mentioned...?

Comment: please mention names of your 5 parameters.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the parameters. But in the last parameter ‘image’ I’m supposed to mention the image path. So considering your solution, what can we give in its place…?

Comment: Ok..but where will the function makeUrlRequestWithComponents be called...?

Comment: in uploadImage() function

Answer (score 0):

Almofire With Image:-

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            print(parameters)
            if Array(parameters.keys).contains(Keys.Image) {
            multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation((parameters)[Keys.Image] as! UIImage, 1)!, withName: "image", fileName: "swift_file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            }
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                print(key,value)
                if key != Keys.Image{
                multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
                }
            }
        }, to:url)
        { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                    //Print progress
                })
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    print(response.result)
                    self.getValidDict(result: response.result, completion: { (dict, error) in
                        var dict = dict
                        print(dict!)
                        print(parameters)
                        if dict == nil {
                            dict = NSDictionary.init(dictionary:
                                [kResultMessageKey: error?.localizedDescription ?? "Some error has been occured",
                                 kResultStatusKey: false])
                        }
                           Completion(true,dict![Keys.result]! as AnyObject)
                    })
               }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                //print(encodingError.description)
                Completion(false,encodingError.localizedDescription as AnyObject)
                break
            }
        }
```

Comment: ..what is Keys here in Keys.Image...?couldn't make that out...:)

Comment: parameters is a dicionary which contain a image with key ->"image", so keys is a structure which contain these keys