# Alamofire 4 multipart upload with header

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

How can I upload with my own headers using Alamofire v4?
In case of v3, I made my own function for that like following codes, but I can't do the same thing with v4.

```
static func upload(method: Alamofire.Method, urlString: String, multipartFormData: (data: Alamofire.MultipartFormData) -> (), completionHandler: (
    response: Response<AnyObject, NSError>, statusCode:Int, json:JSON) -> ()){
        Alamofire.upload(method, urlString, headers: MyRequest.makeHeaders(), multipartFormData: multipartFormData, encodingCompletion: {
            encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .Failure:
                        log.error("Upload request failed!!")
                    case .Success:
                        completionHandler(response: response, statusCode: (response.response?.statusCode)!, json:JSON(response.result.value!))
                    }
                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                log.warning((error as NSError).localizedDescription)
            }
        })
}
```

and I tried with following code, but It doesn't work

```
static func upload(_ method: Alamofire.HTTPMethod, urlString: String, multipartFormData: (Alamofire.MultipartFormData) -> Swift.Void, completionHandler: @escaping
    (_ response: NSDictionary, _ statusCode:Int, _ json:JSON) -> Void){

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: multipartFormData, to: urlString, method: method, headers: MyRequest.makeHeaders(), encodingCompletion: {
        encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .failure:
                    log.error("Upload request failed!!")
                case .success:
                    completionHandler(response: response, statusCode: (response.response?.statusCode)!, json:JSON(response.result.value!))
                }
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            log.warning((error as NSError).localizedDescription)
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alamofire 4.0 Upload MultipartFormData Header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39630997/alamofire-4-0-upload-multipartformdata-header)

Answer (score 2):

Try below code:

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:{ multipartFormData in
     multipartFormData.append(unicornImageURL, withName: "unicorn")
     multipartFormData.append(rainbowImageURL, withName: "rainbow")},
   usingThreshold:UInt64.init(),
   to:"https://httpbin.org/post",
   method:.post, 
   headers:["Authorization": "auth_token"], 
   encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
    switch encodingResult {
    case .success(let upload, _, _):
        upload.responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
        }
    case .failure(let encodingError):
        print(encodingError)
    }
})
```