# How to upload an image using Alamofire SwiftyJSON to a JSON swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm trying to send an image to my API using `alamofire` and `SwiftyJSON`. I've been trying some different ways to do that, however no success so far. The last one I tried is the `base64EncodedString` and is not working. I have the variable styleStrength as a JSON.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]){

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

        self.profileImage.image = image
        self.profileImage.isHidden = false
        self.profileImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        let base64String = imageData!.base64EncodedString(options: [])
        var styleStrengthData = JobSeekerBuildProfile.loadJobSeekerBuildProfile()
        styleStrengthData["Personal_Style"]["profile_pic_file"].stringValue = base64String + ".jpg"
        JobSeekerBuildProfile.storeJobSeekerBuildProfile(j: styleStrengthData)

    }else{
        //error message
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

As return I have a really huge image name but the API doesn't update.

Comment: Dont use base64.Please try to upload image using multi-part.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49047698/how-to-upload-audio-with-alamofire-multipart-upload/49047796#49047796 this

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the UIImageJPEGRepresentation instead of UIImagePNGRepresentation.

> Replace these lines in your code

```
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
let base64String = imageData!.base64EncodedString(options: [])
styleStrengthData["Personal_Style"]["profile_pic_file"].stringValue = base64String + ".jpg"
```

> with the

```
 let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.5)! as NSData
 let strBase64ProfilePic = imageData.base64EncodedString()   
 styleStrengthData["Personal_Style"]["profile_pic_file"].stringValue = base64String
```