# Uploading a file with Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am unable to upload a file (an mp4) to my server.  I control the server and use an `npm` library parse the request.  Now, when I use `Postman` and select a test mp4 to upload to my server, I successfully receive it.  Yet when using this function from `Alamofire`, I receive nothing.

```
Alamofire.upload(fileURL, to: "http://localhost/video").responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response) }
```

I send back some JSON in the response and successfully receive it in my app.  No errors on either side.  What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried using `multipartFormData` with `mimeType`?

Comment: I've not read that thats necessary and see `upload(fileURL:)` and so I'd expect that to work.  I tried `multipartFormData` but got an ill formed url error.

Comment: `multipartFormData` worked.  thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49047698/how-to-upload-audio-with-alamofire-multipart-upload/49047796#49047796)

Answer (score 2):

Use MultiFormData to upload the image

```
Alamofire.upload(
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(fileUrl, withName: "fileName")
    },
    to: "http://localhost/video").responseJSON { 
    response in
    debugPrint(response) 
})
```