# how to upload gallery image using alamofire in swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, uiimagepickercontroller, image-uploading

I want to upload image from with `imagePickerController` using `Alamofire` in swift.
 I have two functions one for original api call which is `ApplyLeave` and other function is for imageupload which is `imageUploadrequestWith`. In `ApplyLeave` function there is one parameter of image i want to pass for uploading which is `leave_certificate: gfg`, this `leave_certificate` paramter should take parameter for image uploading. i have seprete function for image uploading how to use it as parameter in `ApplyLeave` function, and I have `imagePickerController` in seprete class. I really confused how to use this and how to merge all stuff.
        Please see my folllowing code.

```swift
class APIserviceprovider {

    static func ApplyLeave (
    startDate:String,
    endDate:String,
    description:String,
    reason:String,
    completion:@escaping (_ isSuccesfull :Bool, _ errorMessage :String?) ->()
    ) {
        guard let company_id = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: KeyValues.companyidKey) else {return}
        guard let user_id = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: KeyValues.userIdkey) else {return}
        guard let workspace_id = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: KeyValues.workspaceIdKey) else {return}

        let urlString = "\(ApiServiceProvider.BASE_URL + ApiServiceProvider.APPLY_LEAVE)"
        let parameters = [
            "leave_start_date": "\(startDate)",
            "leave_end_date": "\(endDate)",
            "leave_reason": "\(reason)",
            "leave_description": "\(description)",
            "user_id": "\(user_id)",
            "workspace_id": "\(workspace_id)",
            "company_id": "\(company_id)" ,
            "leave_certificate": "gfg"
        ]

    print(parameters)
    Alamofire.request(urlString, method:.post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default).validate().responseJSON
        {
        response in
            switch response.result {
            case .failure(let error):
                //completion(false, "Failed to Sign up")
                print(error)
                completion(false, "You failed to apply for leave.")
            case .success(let responseObject):
                //print("response is success:  \(responseObject)")
                completion(true, "You have successfully appplied for leave.")
                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    let result = JSON as! NSDictionary
                    print(result)
                }
            }
        }
    }


    static func imageUploadrequestWith(
        endUrl: String,
        imageData: Data?,
        parameters: [String : Any],
        onCompletion: ((JSON?) -> Void)? = nil,
        onError: ((Error?) -> Void)? = nil
    ) {
        let url = "\(ApiServiceProvider.BASE_URL + ApiServiceProvider.APPLY_LEAVE)"

        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            /* "Authorization": "your_access_token",  in case you need authorization header */
            "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
        ]

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key as String)
            }

            if let data = imageData{
                multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "image", fileName: "image.png", mimeType: "image/png")
            }

        }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: url, method: .post, headers: headers) { (result) in
            switch result{
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    print("Succesfully uploaded")
                    if let err = response.error{
                        onError?(err)
                        return
                    }
                    onCompletion?(nil)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error in upload: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                onError?(error)
            }
        }
    }

}

class ApplyLeaveController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == self.uploadFileButton {

            let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            myPickerController.delegate = self;
            myPickerController.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
            self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
    {
        let image_data = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
        let imageData:Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image_data!)!
        let imageStr = imageData.base64EncodedString()
        uploadFileButton.text = imageStr
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't require two functions , one is enough , after picking image from gallery store it in a array or uiimage.

Comment: check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49047698/how-to-upload-audio-with-alamofire-multipart-upload/49047796#49047796)

Answer (score 0):

After picking image then call Api in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo like this

```
   var currentSelectedImage = UIImage()
public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
     if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
         self.currentSelectedImage = image
         var parameters = [String:String]()
         let parameters = [
            "leave_start_date": "\(startDate)",
            "leave_end_date": "\(endDate)",
            "leave_reason": "\(reason)",
            "leave_description": "\(description)",
            "user_id": "\(user_id)",
            "workspace_id": "\(workspace_id)",
            "company_id": "\(company_id)" ,
            "leave_certificate": "gfg"
        ]
         Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.currentSelectedImage, 0.5)!, withName: "image", fileName: "image.png", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
          for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
            }
         }, to: "your url",
           headers: nil)
        { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (Progress) in
                     print("Upload Progress: \(Progress.fractionCompleted)")
                })
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    if let JSON = response.result.value {
                         print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                     }
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                 print(encodingError)
            }
        }
    } else {
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```